直観的にカードをドラッグ&ドロップで移動できる処理
カードをドラッグ＆ドロップして、直観的に移動できるようにするにはどのような処理を書けばいいでしょうか？以下のサイトのようにしたいです。また、この処理に適したおすすめのライブラリがあれば教えてください　サイト

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

html(+css)のみで実現したいということでしょうか？

その２つと、jsを使って実現したいです。
